# How to handle such a json properly?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

The problem is next.
In response I have JSON like

```
{
   object: {
       // a lot of different fields
   }
}
```

I use Retrofit with gson parser. What I really need is just this object. I don't want to create class for response with the only one field. All responses server send in a such manner. As far I understand somewhere I need place simple code for fetching that one object and then use default parser for it. 
Probably sorry for stupid question. I used Volley and there was quite a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a special class to handle this (and another special class for every other server response), just use `Map<String, YourRealObjectType>`. Then use this method to extract the `YourRealObjectType` instance for each response:

```
public static <T> T getFirstValue(Map<String, T> map) {
    return map.values().iterator().next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can convert class into JsonObject class. then cal iterate all the elements in it one by one
@Get
ObservablegetData();

Note : use JsonObject not JSONObject